# Error when processing a cube that starts with: The DOM parser failed to load and parse the stream

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

I've just got a strange error from my SSAS cube when (re-)processing data. This is what it says:

> The DOM parser failed to load and parse the stream. URL:'' Reason: 'Illegal qualified name character.
>   ' Source:''. File position: 0. Line: 1.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting SSAS and processing again. It could also be a data issue but position: 0 indicates that it didn't even start. So SSAS might be out of whack.